# Excel to Grid view issues using OleDbDataAdapter

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, excel, datagridview, oledbdataadapter

I am creating a Windows Forms Application using Visual Studio 2010.

I populate data to a DataGridView from an excel file using OleDbDataAdapter method.

Here is my code

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
dataGridView1.Update();

var connectionString =
     string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=No;IMEX=1\";", fileName);


var adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]", connectionString);

var ds = new DataSet();
DataTable t = new DataTable();

adapter.Fill(t);

dataGridView1.DataSource = t;
```

Now Problem is if some cells are merged in the excel file output get bit different.
Here is the image for better understanding.
[image]

So how can I fix this problem ?

I think if I can identify the merge cells then I can fix this. But I don't have a clear idea at the moment.

Is there a better way to represent excel data in grid view as it is in the excel file ?

Any answer would be help. Please share any suggestions.

Thanks

Yohan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string path = @"C:\samples\firstexcel.xlsx";
    GetExcelSheetNames(path);
}

private void GetExcelSheetNames(string excelFile)
{
    OleDbConnection objConn = null;
    System.Data.DataTable dt = null;
    try
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        // Connection String. 
        String connString = @"Data Source=" + excelFile +            ";
        Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;";
        // Create connection. 
        objConn = new OleDbConnection(connString);
        // Opens connection with the database. 
        objConn.Open();
        // Get the data table containing the schema guid, and also sheet names. 
        dt = objConn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);

        if (dt == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        String[] excelSheets = new String[dt.Rows.Count];
        int i = 0;
        // Add the sheet name to the string array. 
        // And respective data will be put into dataset table 

        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            excelSheets[i] = row["TABLE_name"].ToString();
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [" + excelSheets[i] + "]", objConn);
            OleDbDataAdapter oleda = new OleDbDataAdapter();
            oleda.SelectCommand = cmd;
            oleda.Fill(ds, "TABLE");
            i++;
        }

        // Bind the data to the GridView 
        GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
        GridView1.DataBind();
        Session["Table"] = ds.Tables[0];
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write(ex.Message);
    }

    finally
    {
        // Clean up. 
        if (objConn != null)
        {
            objConn.Close();
            objConn.Dispose();
        }

        if (dt != null)
        {
            dt.Dispose();
        }
    }
}

protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    GridView1.DataSource = ((DataTable)Session["Table"]).DefaultView;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}

protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{;}
```

Comment: try this its wrkng fine for me if u have any dbts plz feel free to ask